# Error reading/loading csv file onto Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm getting an error loading csv file onto Jupyter Notebook having specified the below filepath:

df = pd.read_csv(r"‪C:\Users\bino\Desktop\sale_data.csv")

Can anyone suggest an alternative please?

Comment: What is the error message? Without sharing the error message, the community won't be able to help. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you need only to use proper syntax:

***df = pd.read_csv("‪C:\Users\bino\Desktop\sale_data.csv")***
if still it not working then try other slashes in path like  / or // or \ or \\
in your path instead of **' \ '**